# .NET Newsletter Application

Tags: .net, newsletter

Are there any newsletter applications written in .NET available as open source software?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check on [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?projectSearchText=newsletter) they're some interesting projects like:

- [Web Newsletter Application for .NET 2.0](http://www.codeplex.com/newsletter)
- [SPNewsletter](http://www.codeplex.com/SPNewsletter)
- [XZ Mailings](http://www.codeplex.com/xzmailings)